# Access section block fields from outside of the section

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to access the url of an image uploaded in a section field from outside of the section file template.  Is there a way I can access the section, get the blocks for that section, and then the block value for a individual block?  My hope is that I can access the promotions image on the page template that calls the section, but in a another part of the page template I would like to display the image uploaded from the blocks.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="promotions  carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for block in section.blocks %}  
            {% if forloop.index == 1 %}
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row m-0  py-3 justify-content-center">
                        <h6 class="mb-0 row m-0 align-items-center  text-uppercase">{{block.settings.promotion-message}} </h6>
                        <a class="ml-3 btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{collections[block.settings.promotion-collection].url}}">{{block.settings.promotion-link-text}}</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row m-0  py-3 justify-content-center">
                        <h6 class="mb-0 row m-0 align-items-center  text-uppercase">{{block.settings.promotion-message}} </h6>
                        <a class="ml-3 btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{collections[block.settings.promotion-collection].url}}">{{block.settings.promotion-link-text}}</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev text-dark" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left text-dark"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-dark" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right text-dark"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Promotions",
    "max_blocks": 4,
    "settings":[],
    "presets": [
        {
            "name": "Promotions",
            "category": "Promotions",
            "blocks": [
                    { 
                    "type": "select"
                    },
                    {
                    "type": "select"
                    }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "select",
            "name": "Promotion",
            "settings": [

                {
                    "type": "richtext",
                    "id": "promotion-message",
                    "label": "Promotion Message",
                    "default": "<p>Your promotion message</p>"
                },

                {
                    "id":"promotion-link-text",
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Promotion Link Text",
                    "default":"Learn More"
                },

                {
                    "type": "collection",
                    "id": "promotion-collection",
                    "label": "Promotion Collection"
                },

                {
                    "id":"promotion-image",
                    "type": "image_picker",
                    "label": "Promotion Image"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}

{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}

{% endjavascript %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass or access anything outside of the section.

This means that variables created outside the section are not available in it and no variables created in the section are not available outside the section.

So the `section` object can be accessed only from the section file itself.

---

Now that said there is a workaround to this.

If you capture the whole section:

```
{% capture section_item %}{% section 'your-section' %}{% endcapture %}
```

You will have access to the section html. You can grab the content you need if you output it as a data attribute or something else that will be easy to split from the html.

For example:

`{{ section_item | split: 'data-image="' | last | split: '"" | first }}`

and you will get the image from a data attribute called `data-image`.